# How to add 2d sprite to skscene

Tags: sprite-kit

I know this is a very easy question but I can't seem to figure it out.  I've watched all of the videos from WWDC, researched the documents and internet, and I just can't find out how to add a simple 2d sprite to a 3d skscene.  I'm using Objective c but I will interpret the swift code if someone could help.

Thanks for helping.  I'm sure I will feel stupid once I see the answer.

Comment: This might help http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: what do you mean by "3D SKScene" ? `SCNScene` ?